# Get the Bonjour URL from GCDWebServer

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, gcdwebserver

I am using GCDWebServer and starting it by running:

```
webServer!.start(withPort: 8080, bonjourName: "Test")
```

When checking the `[INFO]` logs from GCDWebServer, I can see two messages in two distinct spots:

- *GCDWebServer started on port 8080 and reachable at http://{deviceIp}:8080/*
- *GCDWebServer now locally reachable at http://{deviceName}.local:8080*

I am consufed by the fact that the other URL uses the device name and not the `bonjourName` I configured in the code above, but it's not a big deal.

What is a bigger deal is that after implementing the `GCDWebServerDelegate`'s `webServerDidStart`, printing `serverURL` from there still shows the IP URL.

I can also see that `webServerDidStart` is invoked before I get the *Bonjour registration complete for GCDWebServer* message in the log.

How can I get the human-readable URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property to use is `bonjourServerURL`. `serverURL` is always the IP address and once `webServerDidCompleteBonjourRegistration` delegate method is called, `bonjourServerURL` holds the value. I don't know why the host name in the Bonjour URL doesn't match the `bonjourName` argument value.

Comment: webServerDidCompleteBonjourRegistration is not called on iOS 14.x

Answer (score 2):

This is all about new Local Network Privacy settings. The problem with Bonjour was solved by adding the following to info.plist:

```
<key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
    <string>My app uses local network</string>

<key>NSBonjourServices</key>
<array>
    <string>_http._tcp</string>
</array>
```